# Error: A theme has not been assigned to this store opencart error

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am new to OpenCart and using OpenCart version 2.3.0.2 . I want to change all HTML webpages so I tried to use custom theme. I follow steps from this example: http://undefined.gr/site/2016/10/09/custom-opencart-2-3-0-2-theme/ but getting error: A theme has not been assigned to this store! Please let me know how to solve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto **Extensions > Extensions**, select **Themes** from drop-down. Edit the store and check if the status is enabled and the relevant theme is selected and save.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot access opencart system, you can change the `theme_default_status` in `setting` table, ensure the `theme_default_status` 's value is set to 1 .